# How to cast json to javascript object?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I am using asp.net C#.

where I have follow

```
 CalendarInfo oInfo = new CalendarInfo { title = "Joe Bloggs", start = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), end = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") };
 var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oInfo);
 hdCalContent.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oInfo);
 ltCal.Text= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oInfo);
```

now on client side I required that in

```
[
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2016-06-01',
        end: '2016-06-10'
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2016-06-07',
        end: '2016-06-10'
    }
];
```

Problem with my C# code is that when I used that it is generating like `"title:"Joe Blog"` and it is not working.
can you look to generate exactly how above JSON will be available at client side.
below is my client side code.

```
JSON.parse($("[id$='hdCalContent']").val())`
```

looking forward for solution.

below is the static verion which is valid and working with jquery full calander.

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-06-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2016-06-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2016-06-07',
                end: '2016-06-10'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2016-06-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2016-06-28'
            }
        ]
    });
```

here in my case Events will come from server side from c# code. As I have wrote the code but it is not working.

Comment: What about it isn't right? "`"title": "Joe Blog"` is a valid JSON property declaration.

Comment: Why would your client side require invalid JSON? Likewise, "it is not working" is a really imprecise description of what you're seeing.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Actully I am using fullcalander.js, where event has a dates with title to render. so it has property event which access values as displayed in my question. if I pass values same as displayed in my question then it is working. but from server side by I passed that value it is not working. can you help

Comment: Not with "it is not working" as your only description after I've asked for more detail, no. And you still haven't explained why you think you need invalid JSON (no quotes around the property names...)

Answer (score 0):

You need your object to be in an array or other enumerable type.

```
CalendarInfo[] oInfo = new CalendarInfo[] { new CalendarInfo { title = "Joe Bloggs", start = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), end = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") }};


    hdCalContent.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oInfo);
    ltCal.Text= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oInfo);
```

Comment: JokerManh- but how that would be possible to convert C# object to string and then convert Json?